# How to customize \fg{} and \og{} appearances in BEAMER?

Tags: beamer, input-encodings

How to customize **<<** and **>>** appearances in beamer for a better appearance?

Comment: What do you mean by 'better' appearance? Can you give an example?

Comment: Where do those commands come from?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I've updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Cork encoding:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\og An important quote\fg
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, the same code without the `T1` encoding:

[image]

And with `lmodern`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\og An important quote\fg
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reasom, the `T1` encoding cannot be used, you can still switch to it just for the guillemots:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\let\Oldog\og
\let\Oldfg\fg
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\og{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\char19}}
  \def\fg{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\char20}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\og An important quote\fg
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to cuztomize that \og and \fg appearances ?

Comment: PS: I can not use the T1 encoding.

Comment: @dgs why not? Can you use it, at least, locally? (I mean, just for the guillemots)?

Comment: I don't like the output fontstyle.

Comment: @dgs using the default `OT1` encoding is not the best choice these days. In any case, would you be willing to switch to T1 *just* for the guillemots? (the aspect really improves).

Comment: @dgs please see my updated answer. Only the guillemots change to `T1`  encoding.

Comment: Why it is not the best choice ?

Comment: @dgs The `OT1` encoding has several problems that the `T1` encoding fixed. You could use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `[utf8]` input encoding and you can use the quotations directly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\og An important quote\fg

«An important quote»
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

With the `lmodern` package just type `<<` and `>>` (not the uft8 `«` and `»`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
    <<An important quote>>  
\end{document}
```

The same just loading the `T1` encoding:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    <<An important quote>>  
\end{document}
```

With `T1` encoding you can use another font style with other font packages than `lmodern.` If yoy want change only the font style of the gillemonts, you can use use `\fontfamily{...}\selectfont` in your macro definitions:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \def\ogla{{\fontfamily{fi4}\selectfont<<}}
  \def\fgla{{\fontfamily{fi4}\selectfont>>}}
  \def\oglb{{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont<<}}
  \def\fglb{{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont>>}}
  \def\oglc{{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont<<}}
  \def\fglc{{\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont>>}}
  \def\ogld{{\fontfamily{pnc}\selectfont<<}}
  \def\fgld{{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont>>}}

\begin{document}

    <<An important quote>>

    \ogla An important quote\fgla  

    \oglb An important quote\fglb  

    \oglc An important quote\fglc  

    \ogld An important quote\fgld  

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]